# Firestore react-native - How To get collection size and data from document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the collections from documents to store them inside an array for example.
My Structure: [image: Structure Screenshot]
I want to get all the Numbers from "jobs"
I tried to do this:

```
const getJobs = async () => {
        await firestore()
            .collection(groupID)
            .get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
                console.log('Total Jobs: ', querySnapshot.size);

                querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
                    console.log('Test: ', documentSnapshot.id, documentSnapshot.data());
                });
            });
    }
```

But I got this result: [image: Screenshot] (I'm hiding allowed-emails because it's not necessary)
How do I get all the collections from `job` document?

P.S: I Don't know the `Collection Name/ID`. I want to get all the Collections from the Document and add them to list or store them somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the list of your subcollection if you're using the `firebase-admin` SDK. To do this, you have to use the `listCollection()` method. See sample code below:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const app = admin.initializeApp();
db = app.firestore();

const ref = db.collection(groupID).doc('jobs');
ref.listCollections()
.then((collections) => {
    collections.forEach(collection => {
        console.log('Found subcollection with id:', collection.id);
      });
});
```

using `Async/await`:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const app = admin.initializeApp();
db = app.firestore();

async function listSubcollections() {
    const ref = db.collection(groupID).doc('jobs');
    const collections = await ref.listCollections();
    collections.forEach(collection => {
      console.log('Found subcollection with id:', collection.id);
    });
}

listSubcollections();
```

*The string (**`jobs`**) on the snippets above should be the document you want to list all its subcollection.*

This will result in:

```
Found subcollection with id: 1082373
Found subcollection with id: 2623638
Found subcollection with id: 3644571
Found subcollection with id: 5469434
Found subcollection with id: 60724702
```

---

For more information you may checkout this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document).